# How can I work around installation error of "thin" gem?

Tags: ruby, thin

When I run `gem install thin` under Ruby 2.1.7 (`ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [i386-mingw32]`), I get following errors.

```
D:\dev\myapp>gem install thin
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thin:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

[...]

compiling cmain.cpp
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(uintptr_t, const c
har*)':
cmain.cpp:802:20: error: 'fstat' was not declared in this scope
  if (fstat (Fd, &st)) {
                    ^
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

How can I work around this error?

Full log is available [here](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/295).

Comment: What version of the devkit do you have installed

Comment: @Rots How can I find it out?

Comment: @Rots Installing devkit actually solved the problem. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and give you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri - glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was a known bug in earlier versions of the ruby devkit. Unfortunately I cannot find a reference to the fix.

Install the latest devkit and try again, this should solve your problem.